# Calling APIs in my Django Rest app from a different Spring Boot 2 app

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, django-rest-framework, integration

I have a custom spring boot 2 app which is already integrated with key cloak and provide apis to authenticate users. I just want to use its APIs in my Django rest app or in simple words I want to use APIs from an external app in my Django rest app. I searched for a solution but I couldn't find one. Can please somebody tell me how to do so ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear? Do you want to access the sprint boot API from within the Django app? If so, just use the requests library to make the HTTP calls as you would for any API

Comment: I edited my question. I have a custom spring boot 2 app which is already integrated with key cloak and provide apis to authenticate users. I just want to use its apis in my Django rest app. Or if in more simple words I want to call apis from an external app in my Django rest app.

Comment: @Ken4scholars I will try using the requests library to make those calls I was just having confusion will it work or not. I will implement it using the requests library method and check if it works. Thanks alot.

Comment: A django app just a Python code so yes, making API calls with the requests library will work. You have to keep in mind though that it will make the app slower if you make the call within  the normal request/response cycle. If the request to the spring boot API takes time, you can offload the request code to a background task runner like celery.

Comment: Ok I will keep that mind to check the performance of the APIs. If it takes more time I will move them into background tasks. Thanks a lot for helping. :D